# Application usage report on XenApp 6

Tags: citrix, reporting, xenapp

We just deployed the latest Citrix XenApp 6 onto Server 2008 R2, and we'd like to run an application usage report. I've googled around, but all the how-to's seem to be aimed at XenApp 5 and lower, when apparently it was much easier.

I came across this Citrix expert thread:
http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=265554

Which gives a powershell command, Get-XAApplicationReport, but when I run that on our Citrix Server in PS2 it says it's not recognized.

Do I need to register the Citrix commands in PS some how?

Is there a better way to generate the application usage report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open powershell modules (just start typing in start menu) and then XAApplicationReport will be loaded and you will be able to create report.

BTW there is a third party app that will easy your job. Check [Syskit - formerly Terminal Services Log  - Application Usage Reports](https://www.syskit.com/features/application-usage-monitoring/) for more details about application reports on the XenApp servers.

Comment: This let me run powershell commands on Citrix, so +1 for that!
However, I was not able to get usage statistics from the command... only statistics about the program being published: path, application name, host servers, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You should install EdgeSight for XenApp it has basic mode and platinum license mode,
Platinum has more reports, but the basic also provides some reports, to enable this in basic mode you need to enable Environmental Usage collecting information from the EdgeSight agent,
I highly recommend installing it (Especially if you have platinum license)

Answer (score 1):

Check this workaround out... http://www.itguy.gr/2011/06/workaround-for-citrix-edgesight-process.html

You can measure active usage time by summing the SmartAuditor videos time